# Problema a gerar lista num ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou a trabalhar em `ASP.Net` com `MVC 4`, e ao fazer uma pesquisa/usar filtros vou apresentar uma lista de dados resultante. Para manipular melhor este resultado criei um `ViewModel` onde coloco informação de várias tabelas. Agora para preencher a lista estou a fazer o seguinte:

Crio um variável do tipo de dados do `ViewModel`:

```
var resultFiltro = new FiltroSPlaneamentoViewModel();
```

E crio um lista do mesmo tipo de dados:

```
 List<FiltroSPlaneamentoViewModel> listaResultFiltro = new List<FiltroSPlaneamentoViewModel>();
```

**Problema:**
Ao percorrer um `foreach` para inserir os dados na lista, e adicionando a variável `resultFiltro` na mesma lista, todos os outros dados na lista são alterados e ficam igual à `resultFilto`.

Exemplo de um `foreach` que estou a usar:

```
//Pesquisar Técnico Responsável
            var serv = db.Servicos.Where(s => s.NumTransportado == TecnicoResp).ToList();
            foreach (var item in serv)
            {
                resultFiltro.idFiltro += 1;
                resultFiltro.Serie = item.DadosComerciais.Serie;
                resultFiltro.NumDoc = item.DadosComerciais.NumDoc;
                resultFiltro.ServicoID = item.ServicosID;
                resultFiltro.TecnicoResponsavel = item.NumTransportado;
                listaResultFiltro.Add(resultFiltro);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já achei qual é o problema: Em cada ciclo do `foreach` tenho de colocar `resultFiltro` a apontar para um novo elemento.
Ficando:

```
foreach (var item in forn)
            {
                resultFiltro = new FiltroSPlaneamentoViewModel(); //FALTAVA apontar para novo elemento
                resultFiltro.idFiltro += 1;
                resultFiltro.Serie = item.Serie;
                resultFiltro.NumDoc = item.NumDoc;
                resultFiltro.NumFornecedor = item.IdFornecedor;
                listaResultFiltro.Add(resultFiltro);
            }
```

Comment: Uma hora à procura de um erro destes :/

Comment: Muito bem Cesar. Você pode marcar sua resposta como certa, para que a pergunta não fique pendente.